# Visualisation of proximity of points to 4d-sphere in Python

Tags: python, math, geometry

I am looking for a way to visualise the proximity of points to a 4-dimensional sphere. For a circle I can simply use a scatter plot and observe the distribution of points near the unit circle as shown below. For a 3D sphere I can do something similar. However, how would I go about visualising this for a 4-dimensional sphere?

Is there a way to reduce the dimensionality to project the entire space into 3D? Obviously I can just take the norm of the points and see how close it is to 1, but I would like to have a visual aid of some sort.

[image: unit circle validation]

Comment: Perhaps you could sort of do a "perspective projection" of the 4D space onto 3D. The way this is done for 3D → 2D is basically by dividing each point's X and Y value by its Z component, so for 4D → 3D it would be (assuming points have `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `W` components) `(X/W, Y/W, Z/W)`. The result could be visualized by showing the resulting 3D sphere with a cut-out so its interior can be seen,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to convert 4-dimensional coordinates into 3-dimenstional coordinates that will give you a visualization of the distances of the points from the 4D sphere. Since you show no code or equations of your own I'll just give an overview. If you give more details on your own work then you can ask me for more details.

Take a point in 4 dimensions, let's say `(x, y, z, w)`. Then convert those Cartesian coordinates to 4D spherical coordinates
 `(r, t1, t2, t3)`, where `r` is the distance of the point to the origin and `t1, t2, t3` are reference angles. Formulas for the conversion are in [Wikipedia's entry for n-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates), though in my preferred transformation I would reverse the order of the Cartesian coordinates. In other words, we get the relations

```
w = r * cos(t1)
z = r * sin(t1) * cos(t2)
y = r * sin(t1) * sin(t2) * cos(t3)
x = r * sin(t1) * sin(t2) * sin(t3)
```

We now map that point to a point in 3D space by changing angle `t1` to 90° (or pi/2 radians). This has the effect of "rotating" the point away from the `w` axis down into 3D space in regular spherical coordinates. The distances from the origin and from any 4-sphere centered at the origin were not changed. Now [convert to 3D Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates) with

```
z = r * cos(t2)
y = r * sin(t2) * cos(t3)
x = r * sin(t2) * sin(t3)
```

Now graph those as usual. Since distances to the origin and to the 4-sphere were not changed, this should be a useful visualization.

Looking at those equations, we realize that the values of `x`, `y`, and `z` were all divided by `sin(t1)`. That means you could optimize the calculations by finding only `sin(t1)` with the formula

```
sin(t1) = sqrt((x*x + y*y + z*z) / (x*x + y*y + z*z + w*w))
```

There is no need to find `r`, `t2`, or `t3` or even `t1` itself. You need to be careful for the special case `sin(t1) == 0.0`, which happens only when `x == y == z == 0`. I would then map the 4D point `(0, 0, 0, w)` to the 3D point `(w, 0, 0)` and the visualization should still work well.

There are other, similar transformations you could use that may be more useful, such as changing angle `t3` to zero rather than changing `t1`. This slightly reduces the calculations but you would need to permute the coordinates and the visualization uses only half the 3-sphere, I believe.

Of course, one way to graph that 3D point to a computer graphing surface is to now set `t2` to 90° to get

```
y = r * cos(t3)
x = r * sin(t3)
```

and you will get a graph very much like the one you show in your question.

(NOTE: I changed the formulas above, based on further consideration of the best visualization.)

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for! I didn't necessarily need code, just an idea on how to do it :)